# How do I use Devise and ActiveAdmin for the same User with different login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to use Devise to log in regular non-admin users with the same User model. So I used role id as another attribute and everything working fine. The challenge is that I have to create the custom login page, registration page and other related pages for front-end user. The current route file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Since I want to generate the new login form and want to override the controller I add devise_for :users but it gives me an error route is defined. How could I resolve the conflict?

Also, below is active admin setting:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

I want to customize login page and sign up page controller because I have to add few things to signup form.

Comment: you can inherit user model with admin model and Make another routes for admin you can refer my repo  where i implemented this function https://github.com/uzaif313/projecttodo

Comment: I am not using AdminUser, I have only User Model

Comment: are you suing active admin or rails admin:

Comment: ya i am using rails_admin

Comment: i m looking for active admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override ActiveAdmin in the `active_admin.rb` config to use the same `User` model you're using in your application:

So if your primary devise scope is `user`:

**In active_admin.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
# ...
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
# ...
```

http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html

Comment: This is not the issue, it is working fine. Issue is that currently site is login at example.com/admin but I want another login for normal user at example.com also I want to override few things in signup form for normal user. How could I do that?